# "string" Implementation in Text.Parser.Char

Tags: string, parsing, haskell, monads, traversable

First, just some quick context. I'm going through the *Haskell Programming From First Principles* book, and ran into the following exercise.

> Try writing a Parser that does what `string` does, but using `char`.

I couldn't figure it out, so I checked out [the source for the implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers-0.12.4/docs/src/Text-Parser-Char.html#CharParsing). I'm currently trying to wrap my head around it. Here it is:

```
class Parsing m => CharParsing m where
    -- etc.
    string :: CharParsing m => String -> m String
    string s = s <$ try (traverse_ char s) <?> show s
```

My questions are as follows, from most to least specific.

1. Why is `show` necessary?
2. Why is `s <$` necessary? Doesn't `traverse char s <?> s` work the same? In other words, why do we throw away the results of the traversal?
3. What is going on with the traversal? I get what a list traversal does, so I guess I'm confused about the Applicative/Monad instances for Parser. On a high level, I get that the traversal applies `char`, which has type `CharParsing m => Char -> m Char`, to every character in string `s`, and then collects all the results into something of type `Parser [Char]`. So the types make sense, but I have no idea what's going on in the background.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you post this as a MCVE.

Comment: @Davislor I'm not sure if this question needs an MCVE. The OP is trying to understand the implementation of a function, and not to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @duplode Well, I’d like to help, but the code doesn’t compile for me (using Parsec and hiding its `string`) and I don’t have that book.  Maybe I’m using the wrong `try` or the wrong version.  I don’t know.

Comment: @Davislor Leaving out the type signature, `\s -> s <$ try (traverse_ char s) <?> show s` typechecks with a sensible type if you try it with *parsec*.

Comment: @Davislor If you mean an MCVE in the sense of including the definitions of everything so that it runs as written, then sure, I agree it would help (though I'd say a confirmation of what I said in my comments above would also be enough).

Comment: @duplode Okay, it compiles in ghc 8.0.2 if I use `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` and remove the type signature.

Comment: @Davislor On a second look, I think all of our comments are moot. The title of the question mentions `Text.Parser.Char`, which pretty much certainly is [this module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers-0.12.4/docs/Text-Parser-Char.html) -- it does include a `string` definition exactly as the one in the question.

Comment: @duplode That makes sense. Maybe I’m dumb, but I’ll let this be a lesson for myself not to assume readers will figure out what they need to import.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Why is `show` necessary?

Because `show`ing a string (or a `Text`, etc.) escapes special characters, which makes sense for error messages:

```
GHCi> import Text.Parsec -- Simulating your scenario with Parsec.
GHCi> runParser ((\s -> s <$ try (traverse_ char s) <?> s) "foo\nbar") () "" "foo"
Left (line 1, column 4):
unexpected end of input
expecting foo
bar
GHCi> runParser ((\s -> s <$ try (traverse_ char s) <?> show s) "foo\nbar") () "" "foo"
Left (line 1, column 4):
unexpected end of input
expecting "foo\nbar"
```

> 2) Why is `s <$` necessary? Doesn't traverse `char s <?> s` work the same? In other words, why do we throw away the results of the traversal?

The result of the parse is unnecessary because we know in advance that it would be `s` (if the parse were successful). `traverse` would needlessly reconstruct `s` from the results of parsing each individual character. In general, if the results are not needed it is a good idea to use `traverse_` (which just combines the effects, discarding the results without trying to rebuild the data structure) rather than `traverse`, so that is likely why the function is written the way it is.

> 3) What is going on with the traversal?

`traverse_ char s` (`traverse_`, and not `traverse`, as explained above) is a parser. It tries to parse, in order, each character in `s`, while discarding the results, and it is built by sequencing parsers for each character in `s`. It may be helpful to remind that [`traverse_` is just a fold which uses `(*>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#traverse_):

```
-- Slightly paraphrasing the definition in Data.Foldable:
traverse_ :: (Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()
traverse_ f = foldr (\x u -> f x *> u) (pure ())
```